# Работа с ресурсами не из активити

Tags: android, android-resources, context

Подскажите пожалуйста, как нужно работать с ресурсами, не из `Activity`?
Нашёл на этом ресурсе такую подсказку:

Надо в конструктор класса передавать `Context`, допустим:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(MainActivity.this);
```

А в вашем классе SomeClass:

```
public SomeClass {
    Context context; 

    SomeClass(Context context) {
        this.context = context; 
    } 

    protected void someMethod() { 
        ... ваш код 
        String str = context.getResources().getString(R.string.tvBottomText); 
    }
}
```

Т.е. не просто:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.tvBottomText);
```

а:

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.tvBottomText);
```

Но честно говоря не разобрался. Буду признателен за код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Передавать контекст другому классу (не являющимся связанным с Андроид классами) - плохая идея, которая вызовет у вас большие проблемы в будущем.
2. В чём именно вы не разобрались? Тут всё довольно таки просто - создаёте конструктор в вашем `SomeClass`, который принимает в качестве параметра `Context context` от Андроида. При создании экземпляра этого класса с помощью оператора `new` передайте ему `context`. Context можно получить несколькими путями - через `Activity.getApplicationContext()` будет удобнее. Далее в каком-то методе вашего класса используйте `context.getResources().getString(R.string...)`
3. Пожалуйста, в дальнейшем отправляйте отформатированный код.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, какие ещё есть способы, работы с ресурсами не из активити. Хардкорить в коде тоже плохая идея.

Comment: Александр, только так. Просто пересмотрите архитектуру решения.

Comment: Зачем вечно вызывать эти `getApplicationContext()`? Контекст много для чего нужен и вызывать этот метод везде - бред. Удобнее будет завести константу `final Context context = this;` и потом просто `context` передавать

Comment: Я согласен с Сергеем. Можно в классе application завести статическое поле для этих целей.

Comment: В Application создал переменную final Context context = this;

Comment: >Можно в классе application завести статическое поле для этих целей.      Вот что говорит среда на это http://f2.s.qip.ru/EBATVlzF.png

Answer (score 4):

Метод [getResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) является методом класса `Context`. Класс `Activity` наследуется от класса `Context`, поэтому в активити можно обращаться к этому методу "напрямую", в классах, которые не наследуются от класса `Context` к данному методу нужно обращаться явно, через экземпляр класса контекста

Answer (score -1):

В MainActivity сделал

```
    public static Resources resources = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        resources = getResources();
    ...
```

Надеюсь, не самое худшее решение

Comment: Добавьте больше деталей в ваш ответ. Не совсем ясно, какую проблему решает приведенный вами код. И каким образом это отвечает на исходный вопрос автора.